# decodeAudioData converting an ArrayBuffer to a Float32Array

Tags: javascript, decode, web-audio-api

I want to understand the behavior of the method decodeAudioData of the web audio api, this method receives an **ArrayBuffer**, for instance ArrayBuffer (480044), 480044 = 44 (as header) + 480000 (as raw data), the output of this method in this case :

```
audioCtx.decodeAudioData(theArrayBuffer, function (buffer) {
   var output = buffer.getChannelData(0);
});
```

the output is type of **Float32Array**(2880000). How can an ArrayBuffer which has a size of 480000 be converted to a Float32Array which has a size of 2880000 (=6x480000)

Answer (score 0):

There is no real relation bewteen those buffers.
The first one represents the byte array of a Media File (video or audio) with all its metadata, compressed or not etc.

The second one is the raw [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) data of the audio part that has been decoded from this Media.

It's just like an jpeg file has no direct relation with the raw pixel data to which it will get decoded if you are more used to that.